# Simple Derived Identity issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm struggling with an issue based on the use case that is described here : 
[Use-Case 2: Simple Derived Identity](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity)

I have the following Doctrine entities and mapping in my Symfony app:

```
class User
{
    private $entity_id;
    private $address;
    ...
}

class Address
{
    private $user;

    ...
}

AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    id:
        entity_id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    oneToOne:
        address:
            targetEntity: Address
            mappedBy: user
            cascade: ["persist"]

AppBundle\Entity\Address:
    type: entity
    id:
        user:
            associationKey: true
    oneToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: User
            inversedBy: address
            joinColumn:
                name: entity_id
                referencedColumnName: entity_id
```

Every time I perform a DQL query that involves the User entity, Doctrine performs one additional query per matching User to retrieve the corresponding Address entity. That happen every time, even if the Address data are never used in the code.

I tried to reproduce this issue on a vanilla Symfony installation, and I faced another issue, I'm not able to perform the following code as I get an error (Entity of type AppBundle\Entity\Address is missing an assigned ID for field 'user'):

```
$user = (new User())->setAddress(new Address());
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Do you have any hint or what is wrong?

Best regards